# Rendering an object into a table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am a React beginner and I am having trouble with rendering an object into a table. I can access the ctx object with console.log but I cannot display it on the browser in the table.
If anyone can help me please give me your advice. the code is below.

The goal is to display data from the object(ctx) into the table.

```
function AllData(){
  const ctx = {users:[{name:'john', email:'john@email.com', passwords:'password'},{name:'smith', email:'smith@email.com', passwords:'password']};
  const userdata = ctx.users.map((user)=>{    
    (
      <tr>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>{user.password}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  });

  return (
         <table className="table">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Password</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                {userdata}
             </tbody>
         </table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something from the `.map` like

```
const userdata = ctx.users.map((user) => {
    return (
        <tr key={user.name}>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
            <td>{user.password}</td>
        </tr>
    )
});
```

Or even just

```
const userdata = ctx.users.map((user) => (
    <tr key={user.name}>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>{user.password}</td>
    </tr>
));
```

Another option would be like

```
return (
    <table className="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Password</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                ctx.users.map((user) => (
                    <tr key={user.name}>
                        <td>{user.name}</td>
                        <td>{user.email}</td>
                        <td>{user.password}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
)
```

Also added the `key` property, since you are using an array.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return` inside `map`

```
const userdata = ctx.users.map((user)=>{    
    return (
    <tr>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>{user.password}</td>
    </tr>
    )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code, the main one being that the function that you use in the `.map` does not `return` anything.

Other issues:

- Missing `}` in the definition of `ctx`.
- Mismatch in property name: `passwords` vs `password`.
- No `key` property present in the JSX elements that are returned by the map function.

Below is a runnable sample with all these issues fixed.

```js
function AllData() {
  const ctx = {
    users: [
      { name: 'john', email: 'john@email.com', password: 'password' },
      { name: 'smith', email: 'smith@email.com', password: 'password' }
    ]
  };

  const userdata = ctx.users.map((user)=>{
    return (
      <tr key={user.name}>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>{user.password}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  });

  return (
     <table className="table">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Password</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            {userdata}
         </tbody>
     </table>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<AllData />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```